# AngularJS - Dynamic ngModel with "key.key.key..value"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I know this looks like a duplicate question, but I wasn't able to find anything pertaining this?

I have a variable such as `"settings.page.header.title"`

I would like to set the `ngModel` of an input to the above dynamically, as it will change.

---

I've tried the following without success:

1)

```
$scope.getDynamicModel = function(str) {
  var levels = str.split(".");
  var model = $scope;
  for (var i = 0, i < levels.length; i++) {
    var level = levels[i];
    model = model[level];
  }
  return model;
}
```

.

```
<input ng-model="getDynamicModel('settings.page.header.title')">
```

2)

```
<input ng-model="{{ 'settings.page.header.title' }}">
```

---

Any ideas?

Comment: Just remove the single quotes within the function call in the model attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrote a directive that might help:

```
app.directive('myModel', function($compile){
  return {
    link: function(scope,elm,attrs){
      elm.removeAttr('my-model');
      scope.$watch(attrs.myModel, function(value){
        if (value)
          $compile(elm.attr('ng-model',value))(scope)
      })
    }
  }
})
```

This will add a watcher that will update the `ng-model` for the element, and recompile. Removing `my-model` is done to avoid compiling the element infinitely.

[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/SrvmYi2f7qqb9Iei0oHl?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

#### html

```
<input ng-model="settings.page.header.title" type="text">
```

#### js

```
$scope.settings = {
  page: {
    header: {
      title: 'myTitle'
    }
  }
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/mrcBUNrq90awHaqPYOq4?p=preview

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP meant.

Comment: Yes, this is not what I meant sorry. Need the $scope variable name to be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

A little modifications to prevent failing:

```
$scope.getDynamicModel = function(str) {
    var levels = str.split(".");
    var model = $scope;
    for (var i = 0; i < levels.length; i++) {
        var level = levels[i];
        model = model[level];

        if (model == null) { 
            return model;
        }
    }

    return model;
}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L2GKV/)